# Whether is batch_size default to None in Conv2d of PyTorch.nn？

Tags: pytorch

I found thre is no 'batch_size' in torch.nn.Conv2d (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d).

AS follow:
torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros', device=None, dtype=None)

I don't know whether it is same as keras.Conv2D？

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean there is no batch size? The documentation you linked explicitly says the input is of shape `(N, C_in, H_in, W_in)` and the output is of shape `(N, C_out, H_out, W_out)`, where `N` is the batch size.

Comment: thank you for you reply. But I mean just like this: CLASS torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros', device=None, dtype=None). In this format, there is no "batch_size" ?

Comment: The batch size is set by your dataloader. The Conv2d operation can process any batch size. It doesn't make sense to specify batch size in the conv layer.

Comment: so it can be set automatically, I don't need to mind it, this is right?